# macdeployqt not authenticating application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, macdeployqt

I've compiled an application written using the Qt (5.15.2, C++) framework on a MacBook Pro (2019) and I have a certificate provided by my boss to authenticate the app. This is what I'm running to certify the app:

```
macdeployqt appName.app -codesign="Developer ID Application: company" -dmg -always-overwrite
```

This function call is not certifying the application and it is throwing error which from my research online doesn't seem to be well documented.

First, I get the non-fatal error:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/install_name_tool: fatal error: string table not at the end of the file (can't be processed) in file: ...

Where ... is the path of a .dylib included in the appName.app bundle. This error is iterated for all .dylib files in the app bundle. I have checked and the files are present in the directories. Why is this happening? I can view the files because they are binaries so I have no idea what they're doing inside.

Macdeployqt then continues and reports:

> ERROR: "error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.\n"

I'm thinking that I might be specifying the wrong name for the certificate (I'm not an app developer at all and the company is joking themselves if they think I know that I'm doing!)?

I have two questions.

1. Why am I getting string table errors in dylib files?
2. Why am I getting codesign errors? If I'm getting the codesign developer id name wrong, what part of the certificate information in key chain am I looking at?

Comment: Have you installed the private key or just the certificate?

Comment: I don't think I have the private key? I have downloaded the certificate from the Apple developer site and generated a certificate authority. I'm using a certificate which was originally notarised by another developer (no longer part of the company).

Comment: You need the private key in order to sign code